# I scheduled a task in task scheduler. How can I enable macro through windows command script/ cmd ? I already enabled macros in trustworthy

Tags: batch-file, macros, windows-task-scheduler, essbase

I have created a task in task scheduler which starts a program "xyz.cmd" in 'd' folder. This .cmd needs to start excel  .Xlsm file.

When I'm running it manually it is running fine. But through task scheduler it's not working.. there is no mistake from task scheduler

If there is any cmd script that needs to be added while using task scheduler to enable the macro kindly help me with it

Comment: If `cmd` only opens a file, maybe try opening it from `Task Scheduler` [directly](https://datacornering.com/how-to-run-excel-file-from-windows-10-task-scheduler/).

Comment: Could you describe (e.g. via screenshot) your settings of the task that is scheduled?